# Parallelizing nested loops in rust with rayon

Tags: multithreading, rust, rayon

I am trying to parallelize simple nested for loop in Rust with `rayon` but am unable to:

```rust
fn repulsion_force(object: &mut Vec<Node>) {
    let v0 = 500.0;
    let dx = 0.1;

    for i in 0..object.len() {
        for j in i + 1..object.len() {
            let dir = object[j].position - object[i].position;
            let l = dir.length();
            let mi = object[i].mass;
            let mj = object[j].mass;

            let c = (dx / l).powi(13);
            let v = dir.normalize() * 3.0 * (v0 / dx) * c;

            object[i].current_acceleration -= v / mi;
            object[j].current_acceleration += v / mj;
        }
    }
}
```

Tried to follow [this post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/help-with-parallelizing-a-nested-loop/22568) and created this:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

object.par_iter_mut()
    .enumerate()
    .zip(object.par_iter_mut().enumerate())
    .for_each(|((i, a), (j, b))| {
    if j > i {
        // code here
    } 
});
```

> cannot borrow `*object` as mutable more than once at a time
> second mutable borrow occurs here

But it didn't work. My problem is a bit different than one in the post because I modify two elements in one iteration and trying to borrow them both as mutable which Rust does not like, while I don't like idea of doing double the calculations when its not necessary.

Another try was to iterate through `Range`:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

let length = object.len();

(0..length).par_bridge().for_each(|i| {
    (i+1..length).for_each(|j| {
        let dir = object[j].position - object[i].position;
        let l = dir.length();
        let mi = object[i].mass;
        let mj = object[j].mass;

        let c = (dx / l).powi(13);
        let v = dir.normalize() * 3.0 * (v0 / dx) * c;

        object[i].current_acceleration -= v / mi;
        object[j].current_acceleration += v / mj;
    });
```

> cannot borrow `object` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure

This one I honestly don't understand at all, and [E0596](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0596) isn't much help - my `object` is a `&mut`. New to Rust and would appreciate any help!

Comment: The `object.par_iter_mut().zip(object.par_iter_mut())` does not work even with concurrent access, since the data modification likely needs to be deterministic in this algorithm.

Comment: You are right, I should probably focus only on parallelizing only one (preferably the outer) loop for the algorithm to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is not as trivial as you might imagine :D
But let's give it a shot!

First, let's make a minimal reproducible example, - this is the common way to ask questions on stackoverflow. As you can imagine, we don't know what your code should do. Nor do we have the time to try and figure it out.
We would like to get a simple code piece, which fully describes the problem, copy-paste it, run it and derive a solution.

So here's my minimal example:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node {
    value: i32,
    other_value: i32,
}

fn repulsion_force(object: &mut [Node]) {
    for i in 0..object.len() {
        for j in i + 1..object.len() {
            let mi = 2 * object[i].value;
            let mj = mi + object[j].value;
            object[i].other_value -= mi;
            object[j].other_value += mj;
        }
    }
}
```

Firstly i've created a simple node type. Secondly, i've simplified the operations.
Note that instead of passing a vector, i'm passing a mutable slice. This form retains more flexibility, in case I migth need to pass a slice form an array for exmaple. Since you're not using push(), there's no need to reference a vector.

So next let's reformulate the problem for parallel computation.
First consider the structure of your loops and access pattern.
Your're iterating over all the elements in the slice, but for each i iteration, you're only modifying the object at [i] and [j > i].
so let's split the slice according to that pattern

```
fn repulsion_force(object: &mut [Node]) {
    for i in 0..object.len() {
        let (left, right) = object.split_at_mut(i + 1);
        let mut node_i = &mut left[i];
        right.iter_mut().for_each(|node_j| {
            let mi = 2 * node_i.value;
            let mj = mi + node_j.value;
            node_i.other_value -= mi;
            node_j.other_value += mj;
        });
    }
}
```

By splitting the slice we are getting two slices. The left slice contains [i],
the right slice contains [j > i]. next we rely on an iterator instead of indices for the iteration.

The next step would be to make the internal loop parallel. However, the internal loop modifies node_i at each iteration. That means more than one thread might try to write to node_i at the same time, causing a data race. As such the compiler won't allow it. The solution is to include a synchronization mechanism.
For a general type, that might be a mutex. But since you're using standard mathematical operations i've opted for an atomic, as these are usually faster.
So we modifiy the Node type and the internal loop to

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node {
    value: i32,
    other_value: AtomicI32,
}

fn repulsion_force(object: &mut [Node]) {
    for i in 0..object.len() {
        let (left, right) = object.split_at_mut(i + 1);
        let mut node_i = &mut left[i];
        right.iter_mut().par_bridge().for_each(|node_j| {
            let mi = 2 * node_i.value;
            let mj = mi + node_j.value;
            node_i.other_value.fetch_sub(mi, Relaxed);
            node_j.other_value.fetch_add(mj, Relaxed);
        });
    }
}
```

you can test the code with the snippet

```
fn main() {
    // some arbitrary object vector
    let mut object: Vec<Node> = (0..100).map(|k| Node { value: k, other_value: AtomicI32::new(k) }).collect();
    repulsion_force(&mut object);
    println!("{:?}", object);
}
```

Hope this help! ;)

Comment: By the way. There's no guarantee this is actually faster, you'll have to test it.

Comment: Atomic modification (last example) seems to be ~50-70x slower than nested for -loop (single-threaded)

Comment: compiled in release mode? also, it depends on what he's actually doing. Atomic modification is slower than standard, but if the work done before is expensive, the parallelization might still be worth it

Comment: Here's the code: https://gist.github.com/rust-play/bd6f9afdae9943948e39205f618f3442 not 1-1 copy though (just added constants) + there's the array initialization code for each loop

Comment: Introducing atomics to my code resulted in significant slowdown as well (>10x). What is interesting is that implementing my inner loop as `for_each()` in the manner you showed in rephrased single threaded example with `split_at_mut()` gave me ~15% performance increase compared to two standard loops.

Comment: But in [this simplified example](https://gist.github.com/theYiome/77a5783a192de70cba64e3de1b9526db) single threaded for loops perform better on my device than for_each, par with atomic, and naive par with cloning and only one operation per iteration.